# sha1 java hashing wrong result

Tags: java, hash, sha1

I wanted to hash text in Java, "()_ |**\**\}{][?/>.<,~`", after hashing I have got "82101f0ba1cb0fd017e5b670b7475a95c831d016", but "ef89e75ce03a4fd9df7f9283d332d9a7f01fe09f" was expected. I was looking for hashes on google to test and that one was common on nearly on pages. I hope to always use UTF-8[image]

```
public abstract class PasswordHasher {

protected String algorithm;
protected MessageDigest md;

protected PasswordHasher(String algorithm) {
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.err.println("Operacja nieprzewidziana");
        throw new Error();
    }
    this.algorithm = algorithm;
}

public String getAlgorithm() { return algorithm; }

public String hashText(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        md.update(text.getBytes("UTF8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Null pointer or UTF8 does not exists");
        return null;
    }

    byte byteData[] = md.digest();

    for(byte b : byteData)
        sb.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

    return sb.toString();
} }

public class PasswordHasherSHA1 extends PasswordHasher {

public PasswordHasherSHA1() {
    super("SHA1");
} }
```

Comment: Notepad++ > NppCrypt ( ()_ |\}{][?/>.<,~` ) > 82101f0ba1cb0fd017e5b670b7475a95c831d016 what's wrong? (can't see very well the screenshot)

Comment: there was \\ actually, but needed to change to \\\\ to show \\, thx for help, seems like \ is a problem

Comment: Seems you've solved. As you may be realized, as long as you could, you shouldn't save your hashable data into a String. Read the data directly to byte[] and then you'll avoid the problem with \\ in String objects.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to use Apache commons-codec for this? Always better to use well built libraries for this kind of thing.

If you can use commons-codec it is just one line to generate SHA1 hash for a string.

```
String sha1hash = DigestUtils.sha1Hex("()_ |\}{][?/>.<,~`");
```

Also - you need to be careful about the '\' characters in your strings - it might get treated as escape sequences.

Comment: Thx, seems like \ is a problem and thanks for library

Answer (score 0):

First of all your byte to HexString is wierd:

Use this one (there is probably nothing faster):

```
private static final char[] CRYPTOCHARS = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };

public static String byteArrayToHexString(final byte... args)
{
    final char[] chars = new char[args.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        chars[i * 2] = CRYPTOCHARS[(args[i] >> 4) & 0xF];
        chars[i * 2 + 1] = CRYPTOCHARS[(args[i]) & 0xF];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

or existing libraries.

The you should reset the md after/before you use it.

I also get 82101f0ba1cb0fd017e5b670b7475a95c831d016 regardless of charset.
How do you optain the other value? Some login libraries encrypt the password up to 10000 times.

Or is the unit test just wrong?

Comment: Now i see, have not seen it earlier, if you look on picture there is \\, \ is a problem, thanks for help. \\ change into \ in that editor

Answer (score 0):

You either have wrong test data or your assumption about the actual true hash is incorrect:

```
$ echo -n '()_ |\}{][?/>.<,~`' | sha1sum -
82101f0ba1cb0fd017e5b670b7475a95c831d016  -
```

With two backslashes:

```
$ echo -n '()_ |\\}{][?/>.<,~`' | sha1sum -
ef89e75ce03a4fd9df7f9283d332d9a7f01fe09f  -
```